# Python 2.x to Delphi Migration

Tags: python, delphi, migration, delphi-xe2

Below is my origin python code that I got from someones' blog data. 
I guess it was written by Python 2.x

```
import os

def calcPassword(strHash):
    salt = 'Iou|hj&Z'

    pwd = ""
    for i in range(0, 8):
        b = ord(salt[i]) ^ ord(strHash[i])
        a = b
        c = 0x66666667 >> 32
        a = (a * 0x66666667) >> 32
        a = (a >> 2) | (a & 0xC0)
        if ( a & 0x80000000 ):
            a += 1
        a *= 10
        pwd += str(b-a)
    return pwd


print("Master Password Generator for InsydeH2O BIOS (Acer, HP laptops)")
print("Copyright (C) 2009-2011 dogbert <dogber1@gmail.com>")
print("")
print("Enter three invalid passwords. You will receive a hash code consisting")
print("out of eight numbers ")
print("e.g. 03133610")
print("")
print("Please enter the hash: ")
#inHash = raw_input().strip().replace('-', '')
inHash = '03133610'
password = calcPassword(inHash)
print("")
print("The master password is: " + password)
print("")
print("Please note that the password is encoded for US QWERTY keyboard layouts.")
if (os.name == 'nt'):
    print("Press a key to exit...")
    raw_input()
```

Now I am trying to migrate it from Python to Delphi.
Below is my delphi code

```
function get_insyde_Password(strHash : string) : string;
const
  salt = 'Iou|hj&Z';
var

  pwd : string;
  i : Byte;
  a, b : Byte;
  c : Cardinal;
begin

    pwd := '';
    for i in [0..8] do //for i in range(0, 8):
  begin
        b := ord(salt[i + 1]) xor ord(strHash[i + 1]); //b = ord(salt[i]) ^ ord(strHash[i])
        a := b; //a = b

        a := (a * $66666667) shr 32; //a = (a * 0x66666667) >> 32

        a := (a shr 2) or (a and $C0); //a = (a >> 2) | (a & 0xC0)
        if (a and $80000000) <> 0 then //if ( a & 0x80000000 ):
    begin
            Inc(a); //a += 1
    end;
        a := a * 10; //a *= 10
        pwd := pwd + IntToStr(b-a); //pwd += str(b-a)
  end;
    Result := pwd;
end;
```

Of course above delphi code runs without any error.
But the results of Python Interpreter and Delphi compiler don't show same value.
What is my mistakes? I used Delphi XE2 version for it.
Please point out my mistakes.... Thanks everyone.

Comment: This isn't a free debugging service. Why don't you make some effort to debug this yourself. Compare the execution of both versions. Identify the point where the two codes diverge. Understand why. Repeat until the codes no longer diverge.

Comment: One probably difference is the treatment of strings - in Delphi versions 2009 and higher the `string` type is a unicode string.  Python 2.x could use unicode, but I don't think it was the default.  This would be trivial to notice if you just stepped through with a debugger.

Comment: It is python-2.*, and why [i] in python becames [i+1] in your delphi code?

Comment: `len(range(8)) = 8`, it's `0 to 7` inclusive, so the loop ranges are wrong. Also, looping over a set or array is weak. Use standard for loop. I'm sure there are more errors. It's easy to debug this yourself. If you don't know how to do that then you simply have to stop what you are doing and learn to debug. This is the single most important base skill of a programmer, and it is astonishing how common it is to see it lacking. It's hard to teach I suppose, and you won't find many good text books. Learn by doing it. Anyway, that's your next task. Learn to debug now and you'll be happy ever more.

Comment: @Mae Delphi strings use 1 based indexing.

Comment: I have debugged both code.

Comment: Main problem was occured in line of a := (a shr 2) or (a and $C0); //a = (a >> 2) | (a & 0xC0) At this line two result received different values.

Comment: So narrow it down and just present two minimally small programs that behave differently, and ask us why. Don't make us narrow it down as well repeating work that you have already done. When asking for help the onus is firmly on your the asker to make it as easy as possible for us. All of that said, it's clear to me from reading the code that the divergence happens before the code you identify. So, once again, go back to your debugging and work harder at it.

Comment: In python i shoud be i+1 in Delphi. It's why delphi String has first index by 1, not 0.

Comment: And I converted string to ansistring, but the result has still same value

Comment: You have defined 'a' as a byte in your code. That is 8 bits. so  (a and $80000000) will certainly be zero. Surely a is not a byte in the original? Even if b effectively is!

Comment: @Dsm: exactly. I assume that  `a` (and possibly `b` too) should be an integer.

Comment: The main problem is it Shr command. Is it different with >> of python???

Comment: No. That's not your main problem. shr is the same operator as >>

Comment: If then data type of a, b is incorrect? I tried Integer, Cardinal, Byte, etc.. But the three results are different everytime. Oh my god...

Comment: So do some debugging. Look at the values and the types used in the Python code.

Comment: My guess is that it was written in at least python 3, where integer sizes are unlimited. I believe Python 2.x was limited to 32 bits which makes shr 32 pretty pointless...

Comment: The print functions are a dead giveaway that this is Python 3